# Visualize linear Regression in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, linear-regression, visualization, r-plotly

I'm trying to create an interactive plot for my linear regression analysis, as it can be seen on: https://plotly.com/r/ml-regression/#linear-regression-with-r

Below my model, I hope this is the correct way to compute a linear regression with two covariates (Age and DUDIT):

lm(mFRONTAL ~ OLIFE_IntAn_Short + Age + DUDIT, data = NumericDatawoOutliers)

When I try to visualize it with plotly, it seems to work to the point of fitting the regression line.
Here the code:

```
data(NumericDatawoOutliers)
y = NumericDatawoOutliers$mFRONTAL
x = NumericDatawoOutliers$OLIFE_IntAn_Short
lm_model = linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine('lm') %>% 
  set_mode('regression') %>%
  fit(mFRONTAL ~ OLIFE_IntAn_Short + Age + DUDIT, data = NumericDatawoOutliers) 
x_range = seq(min(x), max(x))
x_range = matrix(x_range, nrow=123)
xdf = data.frame(x_range)
colnames(xdf) = c('OLIFE_IntAn_Short')
ydf = lm_model %>% predict(xdf) 
colnames(ydf) = c('mFRONTAL')
xy = data.frame(xdf, ydf) 
fig = plot_ly(NumericDatawoOutliers, x = ~ OLIFE_IntAn_Short, y = ~mFRONTAL, type = 'scatter', alpha = 0.65, mode = 'markers', name = 'Case')
fig = fig %>% add_trace(data = xy, x = ~ OLIFE_IntAn_Short, y = ~mFRONTAL, name = 'Regression Fit', mode = 'lines', alpha = 1)
fig
```

First, it is warning me that "dataset NumericDatawoOutliers does not exist in data = NumericDatawoOutliers". I guess I have to change "data" in line 1, can I delete this completely?

Then, I assume the relevant error occurs in line 8. Here it says: seq.default(min(x), max(x)) : 'from' must be a finite number. But the variable "OLIFE_IntAn_Short" has a finite number of cases and those are also plotted correctly.
I thought, maybe it's because of 15 missings, but in the output it says: "Ignoring 15 observation", thus it recognizes them correctly.

Unfortunately, as programming newbie, I'm not able to identify the problem, maybe one of you can. Would be very grateful!

Here the data I use:

```
structure(list(Subject = c("v201", "v001", "v0011", "v0012", 
"v0016", "v0047", "v042", "v082", "v086", "v087", "v088", "v089", 
"v095", "v096", "v102", "v104", "v105", "v108", "v109", "v110", 
"v122", "v123", "v124", "v129", "v130", "v133", "v136", "v139", 
"v140", "v141", "v142", "v146", "v202", "v205", "v206", "v207", 
"v0013", "v0014", "v0015", "v0018", "v0019", "v0020", "v0043", 
"v0044", "v0049", "v0061", "v0083", "v0084", "v0085", "v046", 
"v050", "v051", "v062", "v093", "v094", "v098", "v103", "v107", 
"v121", "v125", "v131", "v135", "v138", "v144", "v145", "v148", 
"v149", "v151", "v208", "v209", "v210", "a002", "a003", "a004", 
"a006", "a007", "a010", "a011", "a013", "a014b", "a015", "a016", 
"a020", "a024", "a025", "a026", "a027", "a028", "a030", "a033", 
"a034", "a035", "a037", "a038", "a039", "a040", "a041", "a043", 
"a045", "a047"), Group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("control", 
"pat"), class = "factor"), Diagnosis_Group = structure(c(5L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 
8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 1L, NA, 1L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 
1L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 
7L, NA, 1L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Affective", "Control", "Development", 
"Organic", "Personality", "Physiology", "Psychosis", "Stress", 
"Substance"), class = "factor"), Sex_Group = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2"), class = "factor"), Group_Num = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "99"), class = "factor"), Age = c(24, 
23, 44, 48, 35, 56, 64, 29, 20, 62, 35, 31, 32, 60, 57, 66, 46, 
18, 52, 63, 64, 35, 54, 58, 61, 52, 52, 33, 49, 28, 22, 27, 40, 
53, 18, 19, 43, 44, 26, 28, 38, 18, 50, 45, 23, 38, 50, 36, 72, 
62, 33, 28, 29, 42, 48, 42, 29, 70, 27, 33, 22, 62, 67, 20, 32, 
22, 32, 67, 55, 49, 19, 52, 20, 30, 24, 18, 24, 23, 22, 19, 20, 
29, 22, 19, 21, 18, 22, 22, 18, 24, 22, 24, 19, 25, 24, 25, 20, 
21, 23, 39), FTND = c(5, 7, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, NA, 3, 4, 0, 7, NA, 
0, 4, 3, 4, 1, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0, NA, NA, 3, 0, 2, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 0, 10, NA, NA, 8, NA, 3, 7, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 
6, 7, 0, 4, 2, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1), AUDIT = c(12, 19, 7, 2, 0, 6, 
0, NA, 4, 0, 0, 5, NA, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, NA, NA, 
5, 5, 13, NA, 2, 0, 2, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 2, 8, NA, NA, 2, 
NA, 3, 0, NA, 4, NA, 4, 0, 9, 4, 3, 5, 7, 17, NA, 15, 0, 2, 11, 
19, 4, 8, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 4, 1, 4, 12, 4, 6, 5, 6, 4, 
3, 1, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 0, 3, 2, 8, 12, 3, 0), DUDIT = c(4, 
18, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 5, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 2, 0, 
4, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 13, 0, 5, 0, 10, 0, NA, 
0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 9, 
0, 0), EmQ = c(NA, 43, 49, 42, 56, 39, 45, NA, 61, 45, 43, 36, 
NA, 44, 41, 38, 51, 47, 19, 21, 64, 37, 40, NA, NA, 34, NA, NA, 
NA, 51, 54, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50, 45, 22, NA, NA, 39, NA, 
50, 60, 46, 44, 47, 28, 45, 32, 24, 40, 30, NA, 21, NA, 53, 25, 
25, NA, NA, 19, 46, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45, 44, 37, 43, 47, 
64, 30, 56, 55, 66, 57, 45, 52, 57, 48, 59, 48, 48, 42, 60, 34, 
48, 48, 60, 41, 46, 56, 34, 50), EmQ10 = c(12, 9, 11, 9, 12, 
8, 9, NA, 16, 13, 11, 7, NA, 12, 7, 6, 13, 13, 4, 3, 15, 11, 
8, NA, NA, 8, 9, 9, NA, 11, 16, 11, 7, NA, 5, NA, NA, 15, 10, 
8, NA, NA, 7, NA, 13, 20, NA, 10, 10, 7, 7, 8, 6, 9, 4, 7, 7, 
NA, 13, 6, 5, 3, 10, 3, 8, 7, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 11, 7, 9, 
9, 18, 8, 15, 14, 19, 14, 13, 16, 13, 9, 17, 10, 11, 9, 14, 6, 
15, 13, 16, 10, 11, 16, 8, 12), TAS_EmotionIdentification = c(3, 
2.71, 2.14, 1.71, 3.29, 3.43, 2.29, NA, 2, 1.71, 2, 3, NA, 2.29, 
4.14, 2.29, 2, 2.71, 1.71, 2.43, 2, 2.43, 2.14, NA, NA, 3.14, 
2.43, 1.29, NA, 2.57, 1, 3.57, 1.71, NA, 1.86, NA, NA, 1, 1.71, 
2.29, NA, NA, 3.71, NA, 3.43, 2.71, 2.43, 2.43, NA, 3.71, 1.14, 
4.14, 1.86, 3, 2.29, 1.57, 3, NA, 2.14, 2.86, 3.71, 2.14, 1.14, 
3.57, 2.14, 2.57, 3.71, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1.29, 2.14, NA, 2, 
2.43, 3.43, 1, 2.14, 2.29, 1.57, 1.57, 1.71, 1.29, 1.43, 1, 1, 
1.43, 1.29, 1.43, 1.57, 1.86, 1, 1.14, 1.86, 1.43, 3.57, 1.43, 
1), TAS_Alexithymia = c(2.44, 2.33, 2.78, 2.5, 3, 3.33, 2.83, 
NA, 2.06, 2.28, 2.22, 3.17, NA, 2.61, 3.78, 2.11, 2.39, 2.72, 
2.28, 2.71, 2.17, 2.78, 2.33, NA, NA, 2.11, 2.83, 1.78, NA, 2.11, 
1.89, 2.94, 2.22, NA, 2.44, NA, NA, 1.83, 2.17, 2.33, NA, NA, 
3.17, NA, 3.17, 1.89, 2.44, 2.83, NA, 3, 1.83, 3.5, 2.67, 3.22, 
2.83, 1.78, 3.06, NA, 2.56, 2.78, 2.78, 2.67, 1.67, 3.56, 2.28, 
3.28, 3.33, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.83, 2, 2.22, NA, 2.67, 3, 3.06, 
1.72, 2.39, 2.61, 2.22, 1.94, 2.28, 2.17, 2, 1.61, 1.94, 2.17, 
2.5, 1.78, 2.17, 1.89, 1.44, 1.5, 2.44, 2.33, 3.17, 2.39, 1.39
), OLIFE_UnEx = c(NA, 22, 25, 2, 13, 16, 12, NA, 22, 1, 12, 16, 
NA, 17, 12, 8, 16, 18, 12, 11, 8, 11, 4, NA, NA, 14, NA, NA, 
NA, 22, 3, 11, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11, 11, 0, 10, NA, NA, 13, NA, 
2, 26, 2, 7, 5, 14, 3, 17, 16, 8, 14, NA, 13, NA, 4, 10, 6, NA, 
NA, 2, 12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 2, 5, NA, 5, 19, 16, 1, 
2, 4, 5, 10, 7, 6, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 7, 5, 2, 3, 4, 7, 14, 5, 
2), OLIFE_CogDis = c(NA, 21, 19, 8, 12, 20, 21, NA, 16, 2, 3, 
21, NA, 14, 13, 4, 17, 10, 12, NA, 17, 16, 12, NA, NA, 11, NA, 
NA, NA, 21, 0, 13, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 8, 9, 18, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 4, 14, 7, 4, 5, 15, 12, NA, 21, 19, 23, NA, 15, NA, 11, 19, 
15, NA, NA, 18, 13, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, 9, 7, NA, 18, 
9, 15, 4, 8, 15, 8, 11, 9, 10, 12, 2, 0, 10, 13, 2, 8, 9, 2, 
7, 16, 15, 20, 8, 1), OLIFE_IntAn = c(NA, 14, 17, 17, 8, 17, 
11, NA, 9, 8, 4, 14, NA, 7, 15, 6, 8, 7, 7, 11, 6, 9, 9, NA, 
NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, 2, 6, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11, 16, 9, 16, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 9, 8, 4, 6, 6, 5, 2, 11, 9, 11, 15, NA, 9, NA, 9, 
17, 11, NA, NA, 16, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19, 0, 8, NA, 
4, 3, 11, 7, 1, 5, 6, 5, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 3, 
11, 2, 2, 6, 4), OLIFE_ImpNon = c(NA, 8, 13, 2, 1, 5, 0, NA, 
8, 3, 4, 4, NA, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 8, 7, 2, 9, 5, NA, NA, 7, NA, 
NA, NA, 6, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15, 4, 4, 9, NA, NA, 8, NA, 
3, 8, 4, 2, 6, 6, 3, 15, 9, 5, 4, NA, 5, NA, 4, 7, 11, NA, NA, 
6, 10, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 10, 5, NA, 7, 5, 6, 6, 4, 3, 
3, 8, 4, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 7, 4, 8, 5, 5, 4, 9, 3, 9, 7, 1), OLIFE_UnEx_Short = c(7, 
9, 11, 0, 4, 6, 6, NA, 9, 0, 4, 7, NA, 7, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 7, 2, 
2, 0, NA, NA, 6, 0, 8, NA, 7, 0, 4, 0, 11, 2, NA, 4, 4, 0, 4, 
NA, NA, 5, NA, 0, 11, 2, 2, 1, 7, 1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, NA, 3, 
3, 2, 5, 0, 2, 7, 7, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 1, 1, NA, 3, 8, 6, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 6, 2, 
1), OLIFE_CogDis_Short = c(11, 9, 9, 2, 2, 8, 10, NA, 5, 0, 0, 
10, NA, 6, 6, 2, 7, 4, 7, NA, 6, 6, 5, NA, NA, 4, 3, 8, NA, 9, 
0, 4, 8, 11, 10, NA, 3, 3, 3, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 5, 4, 3, 
3, 6, 5, NA, 10, 9, 10, 3, 8, NA, 4, 8, 6, 6, 2, 8, 6, 10, 10, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, 4, NA, 8, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 3, 3, 5, 
2, 0, 5, 5, 0, 5, 2, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 4, 0), OLIFE_IntAn_Short = c(1, 
5, 6, 6, 1, 5, 3, NA, 1, 2, 1, 4, NA, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 
4, 3, NA, NA, 1, 2, 1, NA, 0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, NA, 3, 5, 3, 7, 
NA, NA, 4, NA, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 3, 4, 6, 2, 4, NA, 2, 
5, 3, 4, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, 0, 2, NA, 2, 1, 6, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
1), OLIFE_ImpNon_Short = c(7, 4, 7, 0, 1, 1, 0, NA, 4, 1, 2, 
1, NA, 4, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 3, NA, NA, 3, 4, 2, NA, 4, 
0, 1, 2, 5, 2, NA, 6, 4, 0, 5, NA, NA, 4, NA, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 
2, 0, 7, 5, 1, 0, 1, 2, NA, 1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 1, 6, 2, 4, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, 3, 2, NA, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1), SCSQ_VerbMem = c(9, 8, 8, 8, 
6, 10, 9, 9, 8, 7, 10, 9, 9, 8, 9, 10, 10, 9, 10, 9, 8, 10, 9, 
NA, 9, 8, 8, NA, NA, 9, 7, 10, 8, NA, 10, NA, 10, 9, 10, 8, 7, 
NA, 10, 7, 10, 7, 6, 9, 7, 7, 7, 10, 7, 9, 7, NA, 8, 8, 10, 7, 
9, 8, 9, 10, 8, 6, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, 9, 10, 10, 9, 9, 8, 
9, 10, 9, 8, 10, 7, 8, 10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8, 10, 10, 9, 10, 10, 
9, 7, 9, 7), SCSQ_SchemInf = c(8, 6, 7, 9, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 6, 
8, 9, 6, 6, 8, 7, 5, 9, 8, 6, 7, 9, 9, NA, 6, 8, 8, NA, NA, 9, 
7, 9, 7, NA, 8, NA, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, NA, 9, 5, 7, 6, 5, 7, 8, 4, 
4, 9, 7, 9, 6, NA, 6, 6, 9, 5, 7, 9, 8, 9, 9, 6, 8, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 8, 9, 8, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 9, 9, 7, 9, 7, 
9, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 7, 8, 8), SCSQ_TOM = c(10, 6, 8, 7, 3, 6, 
5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 9, 6, 6, 9, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 6, NA, 6, 4, 
7, NA, NA, 7, 5, 7, 5, NA, 8, NA, 7, 7, 8, 9, 4, NA, 8, 8, 5, 
4, 5, 8, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 9, 5, NA, 8, 2, 8, 5, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 
5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 5, 10, 7, 7, 4, 7, 8, 8, 
7, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 9, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7), SCSQ_MetaCog = c(2, 
3, 2, 1.666666667, 1.5, 2.5, 2.333333333, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1.5, 
2, 2, 0, 1.5, 1.5, 0.6666666667, 3, 3, 2.5, 3, NA, 2.333333333, 
2.25, 2, NA, NA, 1, 3, 1, 1.666666667, NA, 3, NA, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 
0.5, 1.5, NA, 0, 1, 2, 2.333333333, 2, 1.5, 2.333333333, 2.5, 
1.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 3, NA, 0, 0.1666666667, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 
1, 1.666666667, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2.5, 0.5, 0, 2, 2.5, 
1.4, 1.333333333, 0, 0, 1, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 2, 3, 0, 2.25, 2, 1.5, 
2.5, 1.5, 3, 1, 1, 3), SCSQ_HoBias = c(2, 3, 2, 1.666666667, 
1.5, 2.5, 2.333333333, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1.5, 2, 2, 0, 1.5, 1.5, 
0.6666666667, 3, 3, 2.5, 3, NA, 2.333333333, 2.25, 2, NA, NA, 
1, 3, 1, 1.666666667, NA, 3, NA, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 0.5, 1.5, NA, 
0, 1, 2, 2.333333333, 2, 1.5, 2.333333333, 2.5, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 
1, 3, NA, 0, 0.1666666667, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1.666666667, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2.5, 0.5, 0, 2, 2.5, 1.4, 1.333333333, 
0, 0, 1, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 2, 3, 0, 2.25, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5, 3, 1, 
1, 3), SCSQ_Total = c(91.1, 64.51612903, 77.76666667, 79.125, 
57.51515152, 81.70967742, 67.6875, 72.03225806, 74.19354839, 
60.19354839, 84.43333333, 90, 70.96774194, 65.59375, 87.76666667, 
80, 74.16129032, 87.06451613, 85.40625, 76.66666667, 68.75, 84.93548387, 
77.41935484, NA, 67.6875, 63.60606061, 76.32258065, NA, NA, 85.53333333, 
59.375, 87.46875, 66.625, NA, 86.66666667, NA, 75.25806452, 71.6969697, 
87.06451613, 89.22580645, 58.06451613, NA, 93.10344828, 68.77419355, 
73.09677419, 52.34285714, 51.37142857, 80.61290323, 67.6875, 
55.90322581, 61.29032258, 84.43333333, 67.70967742, 92.2, 56.25, 
NA, 75.86206897, 61.88571429, 89.22580645, 59.57575758, 84.93548387, 
89.65517241, 86.20689655, 86, 81.67741935, 59.51515152, 69.75, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 82.77419355, 87.76666667, 87.76666667, 86.20689655, 
78.48387097, 76.32258065, 93.10344828, 82.77419355, 81.70967742, 
72.47058824, 80.15625, 93.10344828, 82.75862069, 71.84375, 81.70967742, 
82.77419355, 83.83870968, 82.77419355, 74.19354839, 89.65517241, 
72.6969697, 82.77419355, 83.83870968, 78.48387097, 83.83870968, 
80, 72, 81.21875, 68.75), ASR_AnxDep = c(25, 8, 28, 6, 15, 21, 
23, NA, 27, 0, 5, 25, NA, 5, 20, 6, 17, 16, 10, NA, 18, 18, 13, 
NA, NA, 12, 14, 7, NA, 25, 2, 16, 11, NA, 8, NA, 14, 6, 12, 19, 
NA, NA, 19, NA, 6, 0, 16, 1, NA, 8, 8, 16, 12, 18, 14, 5, 18, 
NA, 13, 17, 20, 14, NA, 13, 21, 19, 21, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, 0, 
7, NA, NA, NA, 8, 5, 8, 8, 4, 3, 11, 3, 10, 5, 2, 7, 7, 1, NA, 
5, 2, 9, 18, 6, 14, 6, 0), ASR_Withdraw = c(3, 4, 13, 4, 6, 11, 
7, NA, 5, 2, 1, 10, NA, 1, 10, 4, 5, 5, 10, 6, 4, 3, 8, NA, NA, 
3, 6, 1, NA, 9, 2, 3, 5, NA, 3, NA, 9, 10, 5, 11, NA, NA, 7, 
NA, 4, 0, 3, 4, NA, 2, 2, 5, 5, 6, 7, 5, 9, NA, 2, 6, 4, 6, NA, 
9, 8, 6, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 1, 4, NA, NA, NA, 8, 4, 2, 1, 
4, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, NA, 0, 0, 4, 10, 1, 1, 3, 1), ASR_ThoughtProb = c(3, 
8, 3, 2, 4, 2, 6, NA, 7, 0, 2, 2, NA, 0, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 12, NA, 
4, 5, NA, NA, 3, 2, 6, NA, 6, 0, 2, 2, NA, 5, NA, 9, 0, 0, 7, 
NA, NA, 7, NA, 5, 2, 4, 4, NA, 6, 1, 5, 5, 7, 2, 3, 10, NA, 4, 
1, 10, 2, 1, 2, 17, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 4, NA, NA, NA, 
7, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, 1, 4, 3, 3, 0, 
6, 0, 0), ASR_Internalizing = c(NA, 16, 54, 11, 31, 38, 39, NA, 
33, 2, 9, 41, NA, 6, 44, 11, 30, 27, 22, NA, NA, 28, 24, NA, 
NA, 20, 33, 16, NA, 49, 4, 22, 22, NA, 18, NA, 27, 16, 20, 36, 
NA, NA, 29, NA, 11, 2, 25, 9, NA, 20, 11, NA, 21, 27, 28, 11, 
39, NA, 25, 32, 32, 23, NA, 28, 42, NA, 31, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19, 
2, 17, NA, NA, NA, 20, 10, 15, 13, 13, 14, 17, 7, 14, 6, 2, 8, 
8, 4, NA, 9, 2, 18, 32, 7, 23, 11, 1), ASR_Externalizing = c(20, 
NA, 31, 3, 4, 17, 13, NA, 10, 1, 1, 9, NA, 1, 12, 0, 8, 10, 16, 
NA, 5, 15, 10, NA, NA, 29, 7, NA, NA, 30, 2, 5, 8, NA, 13, NA, 
36, 6, 5, 24, NA, NA, 17, NA, 10, 2, NA, 2, NA, 14, 5, 26, 17, 
9, 10, 14, 34, NA, 12, 11, 24, 3, NA, 6, NA, 6, 15, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 8, 13, 13, NA, NA, NA, 14, 3, 5, 2, 0, 7, 10, 1, 7, 2, 0, 
3, 1, 4, NA, 9, 4, 8, 4, 7, 16, 3, 2), ASR_DeprProb = c(15, 3, 
17, 6, 11, 15, 17, NA, 14, 0, 3, 15, NA, 2, 19, 2, 14, 15, 8, 
15, 13, 12, 9, NA, NA, 7, 13, 6, NA, 18, 2, 11, 11, NA, 13, NA, 
11, 1, 6, 18, NA, NA, 14, NA, 5, 0, 13, 1, NA, 6, 3, 14, 8, 13, 
10, 4, 14, NA, 9, 10, 8, 7, NA, 11, 15, 16, 15, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
6, 2, 12, NA, NA, NA, 9, 4, 6, 9, 5, 6, 10, 0, 6, 3, 1, 2, 2, 
0, NA, 8, 1, 10, 10, 2, 9, 3, 0), ASR_Education = c(NA, NA, 4, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 6, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, 10, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, 9, 9, NA, NA, NA, 3, 8, 10, 9, NA, 8, 10, 
8, 9, 7, 9, 9, NA, 10, NA, 9, 7, 7, 5, 10, 7, NA, 8), MSS_Positive = c(5, 
14, 14, 1, 5, 9, 4, NA, 11, 0, 5, 5, NA, 7, 5, 10, 7, 5, 16, 
1, 2, 1, 4, NA, NA, 9, 0, 4, NA, 9, 0, 0, 1, 17, 0, NA, 1, 10, 
0, 3, NA, NA, 4, NA, 1, 24, 2, 1, 0, 7, 3, 9, 14, 6, 1, 5, 5, 
NA, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, NA, 9, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1, 9, 10, NA, 2, NA, 1, 1, 10, 1, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 2, 3, 1, 
NA, NA, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA), MSS_Negative = c(3, 6, 12, 8, 7, 7, 
NA, NA, 5, NA, 1, 5, NA, 6, 8, 4, 5, 9, 10, 6, 0, 8, 7, NA, NA, 
4, 1, NA, NA, 2, 3, 2, 7, 4, 0, NA, 3, 14, 2, 5, NA, NA, 14, 
NA, 2, 10, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 10, 10, 1, 10, NA, 1, 7, 3, 4, 
0, 14, NA, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 4, 8, NA, 
0, NA, 4, 5, 3, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 1, 0, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
0, NA, NA), MSS_Disorg = c(23, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 
0, 0, 11, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
10, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, 5, 2, 24, 16, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16, NA, 4, 15, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 16, NA, 17, 11, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mFRONTAL = c(0.1002, 
0.1619, 0.1116, -0.0381, 0.0187, -0.1275, -0.0854, 0.1683, 0.0697, 
-0.0099, 0.1045, 0.1853, -0.2227, 0.2509, 0.0884, -0.1922, 0.1425, 
0.1517, 0.1954, 0.0067, 0.1018, -0.0916, -0.2103, 0.0206, -0.0233, 
0.0556, 0.0049, 0.0483, 0.0902, -0.1051, 0.046, 0.1068, 0.1141, 
-0.0123, -0.0885, 0.0281, -0.2297, -0.0425, 0.0754, -0.2105, 
0.3001, 0.3006, 0.0955, -0.0684, -0.1112, 0.3241, 0.066, 0.0925, 
0.0794, 0.0023, -0.0956, 0.1043, -0.1474, 0.03, -0.0854, 0.0483, 
-0.2054, -0.0365, -0.071, 0.0309, 0.1102, 0.055, 0.1038, -0.0273, 
0.2725, 0.0775, 0.5033, 0.1255, 0.1723, 0.0765, 0.153, -0.0509, 
0.2875, 0.0843, 0.0738, 0.181, -0.0414, -0.0433, 0.2285, 0.2343, 
0.2165, 0.0268, 0.1925, 0.0518, 0.1919, 0.0944, 0.0437, -0.0607, 
-0.0815, 0.0976, 0.2082, -0.1612, -0.0509, 0.0597, -0.1558, -0.0999, 
-0.1876, 0.0057, -0.0027, 0.213), L_AMYG = c(-0.2828, 0.1079, 
0.0144, -0.0809, -0.065, 0.1227, -0.1003, -0.0715, -0.0047, 0.0377, 
-0.0882, -0.2757, 0.0407, 0.0559, -0.0376, -0.2928, -0.1817, 
0.0079, 0.1419, 0.252, 0.0278, -0.212, -0.1081, -0.0219, -0.1024, 
0.0671, -0.1812, -0.1238, -0.1516, 0.0641, 0.0997, 0.383, 0.119, 
-0.1193, 0.0481, 0.5582, 0.2898, -0.0977, 0.0675, 0.1645, -0.1839, 
-0.4524, -0.1272, 0.1668, -0.1612, 0.0145, -0.0528, -0.0522, 
0.3645, 0.1759, -0.2488, 0.0289, -0.0059, -0.1244, -0.185, -0.098, 
0.0227, 0.1714, -0.2148, -0.0051, -0.0266, -0.123, -0.1792, 0.3205, 
0.3759, -0.1124, -0.0728, 0.0218, 0.0435, -0.1812, -0.0649, 0.0168, 
-0.1154, -0.0314, -0.0317, -0.0203, -0.1831, 0.0788, 0.2669, 
-0.1812, 0.3061, -0.0736, 0.2177, 0.1058, -0.2297, -0.3326, -0.0762, 
0.2356, 0.1696, -0.216, 0.3106, 0.0259, -0.1149, -0.1047, -0.0468, 
-0.0593, 0.2235, -0.0335, -0.2998, -0.0615), R_AMYG = c(-0.5309, 
0.0311, 0.0662, -0.0462, 0.016, 0.1825, -0.1364, -0.1853, -0.0662, 
-0.064, 0.0112, -0.224, 0.1119, 0.0099, 0.1845, -0.1465, -0.1659, 
-0.0828, 0.1318, 0.0035, -0.1115, -0.1209, -0.0439, -0.0447, 
0.068, 0.1151, 0.0667, -0.0715, -0.2093, -0.0106, 0.0358, 0.2127, 
-0.1133, -0.1324, -0.0139, 0.1567, 0.0959, 0.0112, 0.008, 0.0142, 
-0.1522, -0.2092, 0.079, 0.2896, 0.1176, 0.0155, 0.003, 0.0421, 
0.13, 0.0786, -0.145, 0.2505, -0.1758, -0.0561, -0.1082, -0.2917, 
0.0392, 0.0653, -0.0488, -0.1191, 0.0476, -0.0139, -0.1694, 0.3619, 
0.5153, -0.0549, 0.1472, 0.0607, 0.2295, -0.1706, -8e-04, -0.083, 
-0.1244, -0.0969, 0.0368, 2e-04, -0.3045, 0.1546, 0.3629, -0.1059, 
0.2217, -0.1426, 0.1494, -0.0142, -0.0048, -0.2365, -0.1837, 
0.2142, 0.0306, -0.0843, 0.316, -0.0256, -0.1302, 0.0715, 0.1741, 
0.0611, 0.137, -0.2914, -0.3268, -0.0631), L_aTEMPORAL = c(-0.0301, 
0.1187, 0.1987, -0.01, -0.0467, 0.149, -0.0965, 0.3232, 0.114, 
0.0327, 0.1568, 0.2586, -0.0808, 0.1651, 0.1069, -0.0786, 6e-04, 
0.1679, 3e-04, -0.1272, -0.0771, 0.0847, 0.0324, 0.0785, -0.1063, 
0.1185, 0.0185, 0.0796, 0.0796, 0.0615, 0.0652, 0.0874, 0.2335, 
0.0455, 0.0289, -0.1491, 0.0024, 0.1571, 0.2195, 0.1254, 0.3199, 
0.1374, 0.196, 0.1324, 0.1145, 0.1764, 0.0929, 0.084, 0.2013, 
0.0646, -0.1193, 0.1997, -0.0325, 0.1518, -0.0687, 0.1533, -0.0532, 
0.188, 0.0321, -0.0233, 0.1959, 0.1668, 0.0456, 0.1866, 0.3929, 
-0.1085, 0.1955, 0.0883, 0.269, 0.1775, 0.2185, 0.09, 0.2204, 
0.1223, 0.1842, 0.1668, -0.1406, 0.179, 0.4016, 0.1622, 0.1703, 
0.1679, 0.1321, 0.1369, 0.0923, 0.1127, -0.128, 0.3241, 0.0652, 
-0.1252, -0.0099, -0.1216, 0.0362, 0.1024, 0.2562, 0.1174, 0.1801, 
0.0119, 0.0868, 0.1153), R_aTEMPORAL = c(-0.2239, 0.0547, 0.0804, 
-0.0932, -0.0231, 0.2141, -0.0641, 0.2311, 0.0626, 0.0289, 0.1422, 
0.1743, -0.0169, 0.1459, 0.0399, -0.0982, 0.0196, 0.2487, -0.01, 
-0.0761, -0.0169, 0.0222, 0.0662, 0.0188, -0.1485, 0.1344, 0.2303, 
0.1155, 0.1033, -0.0339, 0.0996, 0.118, 0.1558, 0.0101, -0.0123, 
0.1047, -0.0852, 0.0275, 0.1588, 0.0707, 0.2288, 0.1626, 0.2185, 
0.0806, 0.0741, 0.1184, 0.1497, 0.3015, 0.0313, 0.0255, -0.0542, 
0.0489, 0.0309, 0.0556, -0.0451, 0.0919, -0.0107, 0.046, 0.0868, 
0.0188, 0.1606, 0.1586, 0.1022, 0.273, 0.5084, -0.066, 0.2596, 
0.1371, 0.2237, 0.0714, 0.215, 0.0527, 0.1712, 0.1241, 0.2499, 
0.1802, -0.0462, 0.2023, 0.2523, 0.1661, 0.3844, 0.1296, 0.0935, 
0.1126, 0.0779, 0.0481, 0.0316, 0.3425, 0.1299, 0.0738, 0.2035, 
-2e-04, 0.0868, 0.0585, 0.2053, 0.1247, 0.0776, -0.0161, -0.0076, 
0.1101), mPARIETAL = c(0.0409, 0.205, 0.0604, 0.1205, 0.0373, 
0.1973, -0.319, 0.4948, 0.1063, 0.0858, 0.5267, 0.351, -0.0623, 
0.3925, 0.1549, 0.065, 0.2647, 0.4726, 0.1168, 0.0691, 0.101, 
0.2214, 0.2105, 0.1303, 0.1113, 0.3061, 0.0643, 0.1397, 0.3502, 
0.0457, 0.3479, 0.031, 0.4519, 0.1497, -0.0469, 0.3031, -0.1359, 
0.4121, 0.3389, 0.2197, 0.8623, 0.6276, 0.329, 0.3398, 0.0763, 
0.5494, 0.3834, 0.1228, 0.0936, -0.1259, 0.1612, 0.4462, 0.1499, 
0.2648, -0.0384, 0.4475, -0.0458, -0.0147, 0.1299, -0.0047, 0.5185, 
0.1473, 0.1322, 0.2988, 0.5677, -0.1922, 0.7199, 0.3367, 0.1095, 
0.4, 0.2344, 0.3435, 0.1454, 0.4288, 0.6463, 0.2965, -0.0382, 
0.3013, 0.55, 0.5801, 0.3396, 0.277, 0.4167, 0.2499, 0.3718, 
0.4841, 0.4564, 0.4663, 0.1179, -0.076, -0.0885, -0.229, 0.0172, 
0.0342, 0.3031, 0.4241, 0.4149, 0.2992, 0.1665, 0.4392), L_TPJ = c(0.0362, 
0.2252, 0.0392, 0.1885, 0.0469, 0.093, -0.1626, 0.3247, 0.1456, 
0.062, 0.2914, 0.1883, 0.1931, 0.3303, 0.1398, -0.0425, 0.1833, 
0.3843, 0.0755, -0.0585, 0.0188, 0.2454, -0.0644, 0.1461, -0.2078, 
0.0778, -0.0794, -0.0661, 0.1535, 0.0534, 0.0505, 0.1526, 0.2791, 
0.1663, 0.0451, -0.0697, -0.1288, 0.2807, 0.1774, 0.093, 0.6356, 
0.3196, 0.309, 0.0995, 0.094, 0.2916, 0.3098, 0.1701, 0.2797, 
-0.0141, -0.3866, 0.3787, 0.0594, 0.233, -0.0341, 0.2998, -0.0431, 
0.0587, -0.0769, -0.0832, 0.0758, 0.0296, 0.0713, 0.0542, 0.3614, 
0.106, 0.4146, 0.0851, 0.2366, 0.2777, 0.299, 0.2018, 0.102, 
0.1945, 0.3762, 0.1368, 0.1134, 0.2769, 0.1455, 0.3226, 0.2249, 
0.2706, 0.2791, 0.2333, 0.0347, 0.2638, 0.2935, 0.2198, 0.0998, 
-0.0959, -0.1438, -0.0903, 0.0233, 0.1432, 0.2229, 0.1289, 0.3424, 
0.0178, -0.0119, 0.4322), R_TPJ = c(-0.3627, 0.3221, -0.0463, 
-0.0035, -0.0494, 0.1234, -0.1664, 0.1781, 0.1709, 0.1643, 0.2978, 
0.3557, 0.1108, 0.3032, 0.033, -0.0519, -0.0165, 0.3934, -0.0065, 
0.0907, -0.1367, 0.1376, 0.1357, -0.0567, -0.1565, 0.1466, 0.1124, 
0.1111, 0.2904, -0.0116, 0.1684, 0.1395, 0.2444, -0.025, -0.0176, 
0.1478, -0.1039, 0.0623, 0.302, 0.1259, 0.4578, 0.4349, 0.3154, 
0.1602, 0.0255, 0.1426, 0.0912, 0.076, 0.0765, -0.0439, -0.0362, 
0.4889, 0.1118, 0.0968, -0.0873, 0.3254, -0.0184, -0.0176, 0.2133, 
-0.0641, 0.3287, 0.0357, 0.0574, 0.3329, 0.6278, -0.1143, 0.6235, 
0.0327, 0.2132, 0.0205, 0.1379, 0.1522, 0.2161, 0.1381, 0.5154, 
0.1911, 0.1289, 0.177, 0.2833, 0.3908, 0.4018, 0.2945, 0.3117, 
0.2796, -0.0226, 0.2753, 0.293, 0.2604, 0.1691, 0.0556, 0.0306, 
0.0066, 0.13, 0.0094, 0.0869, 0.1066, 0.2181, 0.0658, 0.008, 
0.4053)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 
77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 
91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I guess the problem is, that you aren't passing values for `Age` + `DUDIT` to your model only `OLIFE_IntAn_Short`.

Answer (score 1):

For `OLIFE_IntAn_Short` only:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidymodels)

y = NumericDatawoOutliers$mFRONTAL
x = NumericDatawoOutliers$OLIFE_IntAn_Short
lm_model = linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine('lm') %>% 
  set_mode('regression') %>%
  fit(mFRONTAL ~ OLIFE_IntAn_Short, data = NumericDatawoOutliers) 
x_range = seq(min(x, na.rm = TRUE), max(x, na.rm = TRUE), length.out = 100)
x_range = matrix(x_range, nrow=100, ncol = 1)
xdf = data.frame(x_range)
colnames(xdf) = c('OLIFE_IntAn_Short')
ydf = lm_model %>% predict(xdf) 
colnames(ydf) = c('mFRONTAL')
xy = data.frame(xdf, ydf) 
fig = plot_ly(NumericDatawoOutliers, x = ~ OLIFE_IntAn_Short, y = ~mFRONTAL, type = 'scatter', alpha = 0.65, mode = 'markers', name = 'Case')
fig = fig %>% add_trace(data = xy, x = ~ OLIFE_IntAn_Short, y = ~mFRONTAL, name = 'Regression Fit', mode = 'lines', alpha = 1)
fig
```

[image: result]

---

Here is an example regarding the input data for your initial model (split your example data in one half for learning and the other half for prediction). All variables used for learning (OLIFE_IntAn_Short + Age + DUDIT) need to be passed to `predict`:

```
library(tidymodels)

learningData <- head(NumericDatawoOutliers, 50)
xdf <- tail(NumericDatawoOutliers, 50)

lm_model = linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine('lm') %>% 
  set_mode('regression') %>%
  fit(mFRONTAL ~ OLIFE_IntAn_Short + Age + DUDIT, data = learningData)

ydf = lm_model %>% predict(xdf) 
colnames(ydf) <- c('mFRONTAL')
xy = data.frame(xdf, ydf)

xy <- xy[order(xy$OLIFE_IntAn_Short),]
```

However, I'm not an expert on modeling and it seems those are no `plotly` related issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this and also check if it would make sense to use values computed with predict.lm()

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get it to work, the obvious reason, I have no idea what I'm doing here. Why do I have to slit my data? I thought the regression model already predicts values that I can use as ydf? I will now check the analysis in spss, but so far I believe results are correct. Is there maybe a simpler solution for this problem for beginners?

Comment: You don't have to split your data. I wanted to provide an example regarding the required input data for your model (a `data.frame` including the vars OLIFE_IntAn_Short + Age + DUDIT).